# max_active_runs not limiting dag runs in AWS managed Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I am using AWS managed airflow to Orchestrate a data pipeline. All the dag runs in the pipeline are triggered manually from a lambda function. I want the Airflow to execute the dag once at any given time. I am using `max_active_runs` and `concurrency` to control this but for some reason it isn't working. When two dag runs are executed parallel both of the the dag runs get executed instead of one getting executed and other getting queued.

Airflow Version: 2.0.2

Dag Initialization:

```
with DAG('trigger_data_vault',
         catchup=False,
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=None,
         concurrency=1,
         max_active_runs=1
         ) as dag:
```

Airflow Dag Run:

[image]

Comment: It is a bug. Discussion: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Airflow itself
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9975

Comment: Damn. I got the same problem. Any idea on how to mitigate this problem until it is fixed?

Comment: I downgraded airflow to 1.10.12. This version doesn't seem to have that problem.